# How can I run Chrome without all browser's controls (tabs, address line, buttons)?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I run Chrome without all browser's controls (tabs, address line, buttons)?

only page-area loaded with specific URL

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you want to open a specific URL (let's say http://www.example.com), here are 3 options for your consideration. For all options, start by creating a shortcut to Chrome.exe, which you will edit by adding a flag/switch to the 'Target' property of the shortcut.

1. **Open as an App** - Use a 'Target' like this:

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://www.example.com

This will open the web page in a generic Windows window, with no browser Chrome available although you can still access browser tools, e.g., pressing F12 to open Developer Tools.

2. **Open Fullscreen** - Use a 'Target' like this:

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.example.com --start-fullscreen

This will open the web page in a Chrome window, which will start fullscreen unless there is another instance of Chrome already open, in which case the page will open in that instance. If you press F11, the browser will return to its normal view mode.

3. **Open in Kiosk Mode** - Use a 'Target' like this:

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.example.com --kiosk

This will open the web page in a Chrome window, which will start in Kiosk mode unless there is another instance of Chrome already open, in which case the page will open in that instance. From my understanding, the only way to close this would be to press Alt+F4.

As mr_kazz explained, you can refer to http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags to see which flags you can use to when launching a Chrome shortcut.

Comment: This is great, I particularly like the option with the `--app` parameter. I would expect that it's exactly how an app should be opened. But when I let Chrome create an app shortcut (e.g. under the start menu — open apps in Chrome, right-click one, select _Create shortcut..._ and click _Create_). But when I use such shortcut, Chrome opens a regular window with all controls and 2 tabs — a blank one and the app. The only difference in the shortcut command line is that it uses the parameter `--app-id` instead. Is it a bug or does it really behave like that?

Comment: use '`--user-data-dir=c:\temp` with  `--kiosk http://google.com` (url must be after --kiosk) to remove the title bar as well

Comment: I want the App mode but without the title bar - I want ONLY the webpage and NOTHING else (and not fullscreen of course). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start Chrome in "Kiosk mode"

Here is a tutorial for windows: http://think2loud.com/868-google-chrome-full-screen-kiosk-mode/

If you are building a more elaborate kiosk solution, you would put this command in a shell/bash script that would continuously run it (and wait for exit before doing it again). This was if your user pressed Alt+F4 it would just start it again.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm using this way, but I need to run it in window-mode, not fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

The above page links to a page with a huge list of arguments, maybe it can be achieved that way. I would also like to know how this can be done.

I currently use this for opening µTorrent server's webUI

```
chromium-browser --window-size=900,700 http://admin:@localhost:8080/gui/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it with the "--kiosk" switch:-

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --kiosk
```

or wherever else it might be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the webpage as an app. To find out how to do so, search a search engine for "open chrome webpage as app" and follow the instructions. I could paste the instructions here, but once you know how to search for it, it's pretty easy.